# set a KineticJS image's offset without moving

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Is it possible to set an objects offset with KineticJS so as it doesn't move?

```
//this moves it
img.offsetX(100);

//this also moves it
img.offset({x:100,y:0};
```

ive tried;

```
img.setoffset({x:100,y:100});
```

but that doesnt seem to do anything?

i know i can set the offset when i create the image as;

```
var newImg = new Kinetic.Image({
  x: x,
  y: y,
  image: imgObject,
  name: 'image',
  offset: {x:offX, y:offY}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position = translate + offset. TranslateX = X - offsetX. TranslateY = Y - offsetY. So, if you want to create the effect of an object not appearing moved (though, by the numbers, it has), then you need to add the offset to the attributes x and y.